# Admobs not displaying on Android Tablets - How do you test?

Tags: android, android-emulator, admob

My admob ads don't appear on any Android tablet device, kind of a pain. I've been trying to solve this issue but with no luck.

The ads do appear fine on standard android phones, but not on tablets.

Maybe i'm not using the SMART_BANNER correctly below, anyone have any tips or ideas.

```
android:id="@+id/ad_layout"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="50dp"
android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
android:gravity="bottom"
android:orientation="horizontal" >

<com.google.ads.AdView 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/lib/com.google.ads"
android:id="@+id/adView"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
ads:adSize="SMART_BANNER"
ads:adUnitId="xxxxxxxx"
ads:loadAdOnCreate="true"
/>
```

Regards,
Sarah

Comment: This problem looks familiar. I believe your fixed height of 50dp is too little for tablet sized banner ads and because of the format mismatch the AdMob SDK refuses to display the ad. Watch your logcat output for AdMob related error messages. It will tell you when there is a format mismatch. If your app is supposed to run on both phones and tablets, create an additional layout for your tablet in res/layout-large. Try setting the height to 60dp. That works for me.

Comment: Hi I tired the quick 60dp fix, no lucky i'll have to play around with it some more

Comment: AdMob is usually pretty verbose with log cat messages. You should be able to find an explanation there

Answer (score 0):

Seems like a Layout Issue. You using RelativeLayout, right? Try to make the ad stick at top/bottom

```
<com.google.ads.AdView android:id="@+id/adView"
                     android:layout_width="match_parent"
                     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                     ads:adUnitId="xxxxxxxx"
                     ads:adSize="BANNER"
                     ads:testDevices="TEST_EMULATOR"
                     ads:loadAdOnCreate="true"
                      android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                      android:gravity="center"/
```

>